При сохранении изменений в VS Code слетает открытая в Live Server страница, если открыты инструменты разработчика
При сохранении кода с открытыми инструментами разработчика страница выдает вот это (якобы нет подключения к интернету) и приходится сначала закрывать все справа и обновлять страницу. Раньше такой проблемы не было. Не понимаю почему так произошло

У вас скорее всего в консоли какая-то ошибка в js, и возможно браузер установил точку остановки breakpoint, загляните туда, если проблема в js, то исправьте ее. А соединение он не закрыл, и вот сервер не может обновиться.

так стало еще до того как я начала использовать js(
